# CodeIgniter Sqlite not working

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sqlite

Whenever I query my database (sqlite) like this in my model (im using codeigniter, full code below):

```
$this->db->select('post');
$query = $this->db->get('posts');
return $query->result_array();
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /codeigniter/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_result.php on line 42
```

When changing the query to something nonexistent I get a "proper" error, something like:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: HY000
no such column: posst
SELECT posst FROM posts
Filename: /codeigniter/models/post.php
Line Number: 8
```

Which leads me to believe the database is actually working, but there is something I am missing.
I have tried recreating the database. It literally has 1 table with 1 column, but I just cannot get any data out. I also tried creating it with different "admin" programs but to no avail. I made sure it is an Sqlite 3 db, which is supported by the webserver according to phpinfo.
Does anybody have a clue where I am making a mistake?

-------- full code:
my post model in models/post.php

```
 <?php

class Post extends CI_Model{

    function get_posts(){

         $this->db->select('posst');
         $query = $this->db->get('posts');
         return $query->result_array();

        } 
}
```

---

My controller in controller/posts.php :

```
<?php

class Posts extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){

        $this->load->model('post');
        $data['posts']=$this->post->get_posts();
        echo"<pre>";
        print_r($data['posts']);
        echo"</pre>";
    }

}
```

---

My database config in database.php :

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'sqlite:/home/******/******/www/wtp3/codeigniter/db/wtp35.sqlite';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Please provide full code.

Comment: ok added all related code

Comment: Are you using latest CodeIgniter?

Comment: yes, i cloned the 2.1 stable from github

Comment: In `database.php`, Try changing dbdriver from `pdo` to `sqlite`

Comment: Is your codeigniter version `2.1` or `2.1.1` ???

Comment: I tried this before, it gives me a blank screen. It also does not give an error (as in, the screen stays blank) when i change the query to something non-existent

Comment: If you just use the get() method without the select, do you still receive the same error?

Comment: yes, i tried to return the entire table in an array like this: `$query = $this->db->get('posts'); return $query->result_array(); `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credits for this fix are with S. Stüvel, J. Bransen and S. Timmer. This is a fix for a specific server, so YMMV. It did the trick for me though.

In pdo_driver.php, starting line 81 change:

```
    empty($this->database) OR $this->hostname .= ';dbname='.$this->database;

    $this->trans_enabled = FALSE;

    $this->_random_keyword = ' RND('.time().')'; // database specific random keyword
}
```

to

```
if(strpos($this->database, 'sqlite') !== FALSE) {
        $this->hostname = $this->database;
        $this->_random_keyword = ' RANDOM()';
    }
    else {
        $this->hostname .= ";dbname=".$this->database;
        $this->_random_keyword = ' RND('.time().')'; // database specific random keyword
    }

    $this->trans_enabled = FALSE;
}
```

On line 189 change the entire function _execute($sql) to

```
function _execute($sql)
{
    $sql = $this->_prep_query($sql);
    $result_id = $this->conn_id->query($sql);

    if (is_object($result_id))
    {
        $this->affect_rows = $result_id->rowCount();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->affect_rows = 0;
    }

    return $result_id;
}
```

Then in pdo_result.php change":
On line 29 change

```
public $num_rows;
```

to

```
var $pdo_results = '';
var $pdo_index = 0;
```

on line 36 replace entire function

```
public function num_rows()
{
    if (is_int($this->num_rows))
    {
        return $this->num_rows;
    }
    elseif (($this->num_rows = $this->result_id->rowCount()) > 0)
    {
        return $this->num_rows;
    }

    $this->num_rows = count($this->result_id->fetchAll());
    $this->result_id->execute();
    return $this->num_rows;
}
```

with:

```
function num_rows()
{
    if ( ! $this->pdo_results ) {
        $this->pdo_results = $this->result_id->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    return sizeof($this->pdo_results);
```

Then on line 60 change

```
function num_fields()
{
    return $this->result_id->columnCount();
}
```

to:

```
function num_fields()
{
    if ( is_array($this->pdo_results) ) {
        return sizeof($this->pdo_results[$this->pdo_index]);
    } else {
        return $this->result_id->columnCount();
    }
}
```

Then on line 94 change:

```
function field_data()
{
    $data = array();

    try
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->num_fields(); $i++)
        {
            $data[] = $this->result_id->getColumnMeta($i);
        }

        return $data;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->db->db_debug)
        {
            return $this->db->display_error('db_unsuported_feature');
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

to:

```
function field_data()
{
    if ($this->db->db_debug)
    {
        return $this->db->display_error('db_unsuported_feature');
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

then line 146 change:

```
return FALSE;
```

to

```
$this->pdo_index = $n;
```

then on line 159 change

```
function _fetch_assoc()
{
    return $this->result_id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

to

```
function _fetch_assoc()
{
    if ( is_array($this->pdo_results) ) {
        $i = $this->pdo_index;
        $this->pdo_index++;
        if ( isset($this->pdo_results[$i]))
            return $this->pdo_results[$i];
        return null;
    }
    return $this->result_id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

And finally on line 174 change:

```
function _fetch_object()
{   
    return $this->result_id->fetchObject();
```

to

```
function _fetch_object()
{
    if ( is_array($this->pdo_results) ) {
        $i = $this->pdo_index;
        $this->pdo_index++;
        if ( isset($this->pdo_results[$i])) {
            $back = new stdClass();
            foreach ( $this->pdo_results[$i] as $key => $val ) {
                $back->$key = $val;
            }
            return $back;
        }
        return null;
    }
    return $this->result_id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

This worked for me. Again, not my work, credit goes out to S. Stüvel, J. Bransen and S. Timmer.
Rather long answer, but i hope this helps.

Comment: It worked for me  but I had to undo the first change:-'In pdo_driver.php, starting line 81 change:'

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in `CodeIgniter version 2.1.0` for `PDO` drivers (They had just added PDO driver in version 2.1.0)

You can see [change log](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/changelog.html) for `version 2.1.1`

[image: Change log for CodeIgniter Version 2.1.1]

Please try upgrading your CodeIgniter.

Comment: I just doublechecked because I cloned from github, but I am already on 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I have Codeigniter 2.2.1 and when I set application/config/database.php the same as OP I can use sqlite database, sort of. I can create new database/file, create new tables and insert data. The problem is that I can't read any.

```
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');
return $query->result_array();
```

Returns empty array. The same happens when I do.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT...");
```

Apparently there are still some bugs. I'm just starting to explore Codeigniter, but when I switch to mysql the same exact Model works as it should.

For the record, everything on my server is set up OK. I can use my sqlite databases just fine, it is just Codeigniter that has problems.

Answer (score 0):

I applied g_m solution after updating from 2.1.3 to 2.2.6, and as jimmy, I had to remove the first change in pdo_driver.php to make it work.