# sqlite3 configuration for codeigniter 2.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlite

I am using sqlite for the first time and so I am having problems in configuring it with codeigniter 2.2.

I have put my sqlite database in:- `application/config/sqlite/sqlite-database.db`

and my configuration is:-

```
    $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['default']['username'] = '';
    $db['default']['password'] = '';
    $db['default']['database'] = 'sqlite/sqlite-database.db';
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlite';
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I am not able to connect to database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with something like this:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'sqlite:'.APPPATH.'config/sqlite/sqlite-database.db';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced one more problem for which I got the solution at:- 
[CodeIgniter Sqlite not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941817/codeigniter-sqlite-not-working)

I am sharing this because many of you would face this problem while using codeigniter and sqlite