# Codeigniter returns no rows of any sqlite3 table

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo, sqlite

I am a beginner (more or less 1 month) in CodeIgniter and I'm trying to make it work with a sqlite3 database, and I'm stumped. What am I missing?

I used [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757213/sqlite3-configuration-for-codeigniter-2-2) to configure it hoping that it's not the cause of this problem.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'sqlite:'.APPPATH.'db/******.s3db';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

here's my model:

```
<?php
class QuoteModel extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function getQuote() {
        $query = $this->db->get('quote');
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

Changing the table name to something not in the database generates an error, which made me think that connection to the database works:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: HY000
no such table: unknown_table
SELECT * FROM unknown_table
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\*****\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

By changing the `table_name` to any other table in the database, the `$this->db->last_query()` looks ok and executes correctly in my SQLiteStudio with a number of rows returned, but `$query->num_rows()` returns 0.

There's no error but only a warning in the PHP log which is probably not related to my problem:

```
[22-Nov-2015 23:37:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'oci8' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I use XAMPP 1.8.3 with PHP 5.5.15, PDO support PDO drivers enabled mysql, sqlite and PDO driver for SQLite 3.x SQLite Library enabled 3.8.4.3, CodeIgniter 2.2 in Windows 7 Prof SP1 64bit.

Please help.

Comment: database is sqlite, I don't think we need username or password to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great office-mate suggested to try it in CodeIgniter 3. Then I am happy.

In my database.php, username, password and database name are all empty:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'sqlite:'.APPPATH.'db/******.s3db',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0.3, the current version of the framework as of this date.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$db['default']['username'] = 'DATABASE USERNAME';

$db['default']['password'] = 'IF USER HAS A PASSWORD';

$db['default']['database'] = 'DATABASE NAME HERE';

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlite';
```

Comment: I tried it by leaving the username and password blank because it's a sqlite database, and set the database to `APPPATH.'db/******.s3db'` because as CI guide says, the "database name will be the path to your database file", then the dbdriver to `'sqlite'` as you suggested. The page turned blank. If that's how to do it, no, it doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941817/codeigniter-sqlite-not-working#24863782

Answer (score 0):

your databse name is empty. i think that is wrong.

To cross check

```
function test()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();
    print_r($CI->db);
}
```

Above code will print all variables you have set in `database.php`.

Also try setting your database name.